# Send http GET command from Telnet

Tags: http, go, telnet

I have this simple program:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/users", UsersHandler)

    fmt.Println("Starting server...")

    http.ListenAndServe(":8181", nil)
}

func UsersHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("Users")
}
```

If I send a `GET` command from the browser: `http://localhost:8181` I can see the message "Users" printed, but If I connect from telnet no message is printed when I do:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 8181
GET /users HTTP/1.1
```

Any idea why is that ?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Go, from Google (www.golang.org)

Comment: What happens if you hit ENTER a second time after typing your `GET` command?

Comment: Cannot believe that was the problem, now I can see the message :/

Comment: You should add the answer so I can accepted it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to enter a second carriage return, which signifies the end of the headers block.